# Get text from file and display in Jenkins email content

Tags: jenkins, email-ext

I have constructed Build version from a config file and saved this version number value to a file which resides in my workspace.
The contents of this file will contain values like
     2014.4.3.87

Now, I need to get this value on to the Jenkins e-mail body.
I have email ext plugin installed. How do i do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a shell command echo the file content and save it into a into a another file, like content="real content"

For example:

```
fileContent="content=$(echo filepath)"
```

You can use env inject plugin to inject this file "filecontent" as env.

Then inside the email ext plugin, try use this to read it
`${ENV, var="content"}` in the file content text area

Answer (score 3):

In Post-build actions - Editable Email Notification

1. Ensure Content Type is set to html.
2. In Default Content add ${FILE,path="workspace_relative_filepath"}.